# Android Studio : Reset/Restore “Remember, don't ask again” (or "Do not show this dialog in future")

Tags: android-studio

By pressing `CTRL`+`ALT`+`L` , a dialog box opens up which contains many options like `Reformat Code`, `Optimize Code`, etc.

I mistakenly enabled check for `Remember, don't ask again`. Now that dialog box is not opening up. I want that dialog box to show. I went through all the options in the `Settings` but no luck.

Somebody please help! TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following box:

```
Settings > Editor > General > Formatting > Show "Reformat Code" dialog
```